# public function assignData($data) não é chamada

Tags: magento

Em um modulo de pagamento que estou testando,uso a classe `payment.phtl` que extende de `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` e, para fins de teste, coloquei uma saída para um arquivo de log em duas funções, `public function assignData($data)` e `public function validate()`, tanto na minha classe quanto na classe original do Magento e verifiquei no log que a função `assignData($data)` original foi chamada e na minha classe não, apesar da função `validate()` ser chamada nas duas classes.
Obrigado por qualquer ajuda.

**Esta função desta classe não é chamada**

```
class Oitoo_Cielo_Model_Payment extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

    /**=====================================
     * Assign data to info model instance
     *
     * @param   mixed $data
     * @return  Mage_Payment_Model_Info
     ======================================*/
    public function assignData($data)
    {
Mage::log(' 88 =>  assignData  ' ,  null, 'cielo.log'); 
        if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
            $data = new Varien_Object($data);
        }
        $info = $this->getInfoInstance();
        //zera os juros para evitar erros
        $info->getQuote()->setJuros(0.0);
        $info->getQuote()->setBaseJuros(0.0);
        $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setJuros(0.0);
        $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setBaseJuros(0.0);
        $info->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

        //zera o valor do desconto para evitar erros
        $info->getQuote()->setDesconto(0.0);
        $info->getQuote()->setBaseDesconto(0.0);
        $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setDesconto(0.0);
        $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setBaseDesconto(0.0);
        $info->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();


        $info->setCcType($data->getBandeiraCielo())
            ->setAdditionalData($data->getParcelasCielo())
            ->setCcOwner($data->getPortadorCielo())
            ->setCcLast4(substr($data->getNumeroCartaoCielo(), -4))
            //->setCcNumber($data->getCcNumber())
            //->setCcCid($data->getCcCid())
            ->setCcExpMonth($data->getExpiracaoMesCielo())
            ->setCcExpYear($data->getExpiracaoAnoCielo())
            ->setCcCid($info->encrypt($data->getCodigoSegurancaCielo())) //criptografa o código de segurança do cartão
            ->setCcNumber($info->encrypt(str_replace(' ', '',$data->getNumeroCartaoCielo()))) //criptografa o numero do cartão
        ;

        $parcela        =   $data->getParcelasCielo();
        $valorTotal     =   $info->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
       // $valorDesconto  =   Mage::helper('apelidocielo')->getDiscountAmount($parcela,$valorTotal);
       /* if($valorDesconto > 0):
               // Mage::helper('apelidocielo')->setDiscountQuote($info,$valorDesconto);
        endif;*/

        //verifica se tem juros e aplica no carrinho. Se o retorno do getJurosAmount for maior que 0, aplica no quote.
        $valorJuros    =    Mage::helper('apelidocielo')->getJurosAmount($parcela,$valorTotal);
        $valorDesconto =    -(Mage::helper('apelidocielo')->getDiscountAmount($parcela,$valorTotal));


        if($valorJuros > 0):
            $info->getQuote()->setJuros($valorJuros);
            $info->getQuote()->setBaseJuros($valorJuros);
            $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setJuros($valorJuros);
            $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setBaseJuros($valorJuros);
            $info->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

        else:
            $info->getQuote()->setJuros(0.0);
            $info->getQuote()->setBaseJuros(0.0);
            $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setJuros(0.0);
            $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setBaseJuros(0.0);
            $info->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

        endif;



        if($valorDesconto < 0):
            $info->getQuote()->setDesconto($valorDesconto);
            $info->getQuote()->setBaseDesconto($valorDesconto);
            $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setDesconto($valorDesconto);
            $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setBaseDesconto($valorDesconto);
            $info->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

        else:
            $info->getQuote()->setDesconto(0.0);
            $info->getQuote()->setBaseDesconto(0.0);
            $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setDesconto(0.0);
            $info->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setBaseDesconto(0.0);
            $info->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

        endif;


        $info->getQuote()->save();

        return $this;
    }
```

**Esta função é chamada mas como não passou na primeira os dados não são recuperados.**

```
 public function validate() {

        $info     = $this->getInfoInstance();
        $ccNumber = Mage::helper('core')->decrypt($info->getCcNumber());
        $bandeira = $info->getCcType();
        $validado = false;

Mage::log('178 =>  Bandeira  ' . $bandeira. ' ccnumber ' . $ccNumber ,  null, 'cielo.log');

        if (Mage::helper('apelidocielo')->validateCcNum($ccNumber))
        {
            $ccTypeRegExp = '/^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$/'; //visa
            if (preg_match($ccTypeRegExp, $ccNumber) && $bandeira == 'visa')
            {
                $validado = true;
            }

            $ccTypeRegExp = '/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/'; //mastercard
            if (preg_match($ccTypeRegExp, $ccNumber) && $bandeira == 'mastercard')
            {
                $validado = true;
            }

            $ccTypeRegExp = '/^3[47][0-9]{13}$/'; //amex
            if (preg_match($ccTypeRegExp, $ccNumber) && $bandeira == 'amex')
            {
                $validado = true;
            }

            $ccTypeRegExp = '/^6011[0-9]{12}$/'; //discover
            if (preg_match($ccTypeRegExp, $ccNumber) && $bandeira == 'discover')
            {
                $validado = true;
            }

            $ccTypeRegExp = '/^(3[0-9]{15}|(2131|1800)[0-9]{11})$/'; //jcb
            if (preg_match($ccTypeRegExp, $ccNumber) && $bandeira == 'jcb')
            {
                $validado = true;
            }

            $ccTypeRegExp = '/^3[0,6,8]\d{12}$/'; //diners
            if (preg_match($ccTypeRegExp, $ccNumber) && $bandeira == 'diners')
            {
                $validado = true;
            }

            if ($bandeira == 'elo' || $bandeira == 'aura')
            {
                $validado = true;
            }
        } else {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('payment')->__('O número do cartão digitado não é válido.'));
        }

        if(!$validado):
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('payment')->__('O número do cartão de crédito não é válido para bandeira selecionada: ' . $bandeira));
        endif;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Clique em [edit] e poste o código que você está tendo dificuldades para facilitar te ajudarem.